# Convert the sql code to sqlite code

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Below SQL query is perfectly working in SQL database. But not working in SQLITE. Please convert this to work in Android-SQLITE DB. Thanks.

```
delete contacts from contacts inner join 
    (select  min(id) minid, user_email, name, number
     from contacts 
     group by user_email, name, number
     having count(1) > 1) as duplicates
   on (duplicates.name = contacts.name
   and duplicates.number = contacts.number
   and duplicates.minid <> contacts.id)
```

Comment: stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please show what you have tried and try to change the question accordingly. This article might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example, provide the error message you are getting, or provide a mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can use a tool like http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to try out your query. You'll quickly realize `DELETE contacts` will not work, the query must be of the form `DELETE FROM contacts WHERE ...` and then rewrite your condition. Good luck :)

Comment: I posted an answer when I suddenly noticed that you group by `user_email` but don't access it afterwards. That means: You only consider records duplicates when the triplet **user_email** + name + number occurs more than once. But then you delete records that you didn't consider duplicates (those with the same name and number and *different* user_email). You are sure this statement is "perfectly working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments section I explain why I doubt your delete statement to be correct. Either you shouldn't group by `user_email` or have `user_email` in the `ON` clause, too. In case I am right, read on:

The delete statement you are showing uses a join. I don't know why it was written thus, because it can easily be written without. A mere `DELETE` with an `EXISTS` clause that says: delete all records for which exists another record with the same name and number and a lower ID.

```
delete from contacts  -- edited
where exists
(
  select *
  from contacts other
  where other.name = contacts.name
    and other.number = contacts.number
    and other.user_email = contacts.user_email -- decide whether you want this line or not
    and other.id < contacts.id
);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in about every RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, but an explanation.**

---

Illustration of your delete statement:

**sample 1:**

```
id   user_email   name   number
1    a@x.com      a      100
2    a@x.com      a      100
3    a@y.com      a      100
```

The first two lines are seen as duplicates. The minimum ID for the duplicate is 1. All records with name 'a' and number 100 and ID ≠ 1 get deleted. This includes ID 3 which was not considered a duplicate.

**sample 2:**

```
id   user_email   name   number
1    a@x.com      a      100
2    a@y.com      a      100
3    a@y.com      a      100
```

Lines two and three are seen as duplicates. The minimum ID for the duplicate is 2. All records with name 'a' and number 100 and ID ≠ 2 get deleted. This includes ID 1 which was not considered a duplicate.

**sample 3:**

```
id   user_email   name   number
1    a@x.com      a      100
2    a@x.com      a      100
3    a@y.com      a      100
4    a@y.com      a      100
```

Lines one and two are seen as duplicates and lines three and four are also seen as duplicates. The minimum ID for the first duplicate is 1. The minimum ID for the second duplicate is 3. All records with name 'a' and number 100 and ID ≠ 2 get deleted. This includes ID 3. Also all records with name 'a' and number 100 and ID ≠ 3 get deleted. This includes ID 2. So *all* records get deleted.